# Files not found when using PHP variables

Tags: php, html, css, http-status-code-404

Hello (English isn't my first language so foregive me for any mistakes),

I'm working on an extra school project, the goal of the project is to design and code a forum website. I'm using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP for this project. I'm verry new to the last two. I use JavaScript to check if a password meads all the requirements. Captial letters, numbers etc. PHP is used to import the data from a form in a MySql database and for variables.

I'm currently working on the main and the registration page. I got the hole registration process working with help from a YouTube video. I'm now trying to make a few "template div's" so when I have for example 10 pages and I change the title of the website I don't have to open every file in order to change it. I'm currently using php define to create a variable (I think) and that variable is placed in every page. I currently got this working in the index page, but when I go to the registration page every image and links to other page's don't work. The problem is that it searches the image or file inside of the folder where the registration page is located. But the image is inside the Root/CSS/Images/Registration folder and not in Root/Registration/CSS/Images/Registration.

So in short,
Is there a way to locate a file from every page without using an absolute url?

I tried the following:
Useing ../ in front of the path, but this doesn't work when going back to the index file.

Useing an absolute url for example. D/OneDrive/Documents/School/Website/Host/CSS/Images/. This only works when the website is in this path. But when I move it an actual server this obviously doesn't work because the path is wrong.

The index file:

```
<?php
require_once('PHP/config.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo  title; ?></title>
    <link rel="icon" href="CSS/Images/icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='CSS/style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo  header; ?>
</body>

<footer class="footer"><?php echo  footer; ?></footer>
</html>
```

The config/varible file:

```
<?php
define('title','Martijns Forum');
define('footer', '*All the footer code*');
define('header', '
    <div class="banner">
        <img src="CSS/Images/banner.jpg">
        *All the other banner code*
    </div>'
?>
```

I expected the 404 error because I don't know another way how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use absolute URL`s, than you need to change URL when the page is deployed on a server.
Absolute URL should be used like this:

```
<?php echo SERVER_URL.'/CSS/Images/icon.png'; ?>
```

You must change the SERVER URL to your server IP address or domain name.

```
<?php
   define('SERVER_URL', 'http://8.8.8.8');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating one more constant. In the case below, I will use INCLUDE_PATH as a constant. And set in it the default full URL of the folder where the page documents are, in which case I'll use as an example https://mydomain/

```
    <?php
    define('INCLUDE_PATH','https://mydomain/');
    define('title','Martijns Forum');
    define('footer', '*All the footer code*');
    define('header', '
     <div class="banner">
        <img src="CSS/Images/banner.jpg">
        *All the other banner code*
     </div>');
    ?>
```

Now use the echo function and call the include_path constant on all page requests, in this case at the beginning of css. It would look something like this:

```
<?php
require_once('PHP/config.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo  title; ?></title>
    <link rel="icon" href="<?php INCLUDE_PATH; ?>CSS/Images/icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php INCLUDE_PATH; ?>CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo  header; ?>
</body>

<footer class="footer"><?php echo  footer; ?></footer>
</html>
```